# How to fix Google expo auth session sign in Error "Something went wrong when trying to finish signing in"

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, google-signin

I'm trying to implement google sign in in my expo using [expo-auth-session](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/auth-session/),
When I click on my gmail to sign in, I'm redirected to this [screen](https://ibb.co/hBc6CMz) saying "Something went wrong when trying to finish signing in. Please close this screen to go back to the app".

```
//Google auth code:
    import * as Google from 'expo-auth-session/providers/google';
    const [request, response, promptAsync] = Google.useAuthRequest({
        expoClientId: config.google.expoClientId,
        redirectUri: config.google.redirectUri,
      });

      React.useEffect(() => {
      //Handle google login
      console.log(response)
      if (response?.type === 'success') {
       const { authentication } = response;
      } 
      }, [response]);

    //Button that calls the google sign in
    <Button iconName={'google'} iconPressed={() => promptAsync({useProxy: true})} />
```

Comment: This is an open issue. [Here](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/8957) the github page.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I've seen the github but none of the comment there helped me, was hoping if someone here could provide some guidance. @GiovanniEsposito

Comment: So you already tried to set `useProxy: false` correct?

Comment: I did, yes. @GiovanniEsposito

Comment: same issue with me. here is my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73136119/expo-auth-session-cannot-complete-google-login-on-android-standalone-app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [expo-google-app-auth](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/google/), for some reason that I'm yet to figure out, you have to use host.expo.exponent as your package name and bundle identifier in the google developer console for this library to work.
Code:

```
import { Alert } from 'react-native';
import * as Google from 'expo-google-app-auth'

const GoogleLogin = async () => {
    //Get those keys from the google developer console
    const { iosClientId, androidClientId } = config.google
    const { type, user } = await Google.logInAsync({
        iosClientId,
        androidClientId,
    });

    if (type === 'success') {
        /* `accessToken` is now valid and can be used to get data from the Google API with HTTP requests */
        return { email: user.email, id: user.id }
    } else {
        Alert.alert("Google login error.")
    }
}

export default GoogleLogin;
```

Comment: what if I use my custom package & bundle name like `com.bilal.profile` instead of `host.expo.exponent `?

Answer (score 1):

If someone is trying this now.

You can Follow This https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hmZm_jPvWWM

In the code given in this video
replace promptAsync({useProxy: false, showInRecents: true}) => promptAsync()

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try like this

```
import * as Google from 'expo-auth-session/providers/google';
import * as WebBrowser from 'expo-web-browser';

WebBrowser.maybeCompleteAuthSession();
....
const [request, response, promptAsync] = Google.useAuthRequest({
        androidClientId: config.androidClientId,
        iosClientId: config.iosClientId,
        expoClientId: config.expoClientId,
        scopes: config.scopes,
    });

useEffect(() => {
   if (response?.type === 'success') {
       const { authentication } = response;
       getGoogleUser((authentication as any).accessToken)
   }
}, [response]);

const getGoogleUser = async (accessToken: string) => {

  try{
        const response = await fetch('https://www.googleapis.com/userinfo/v2/me', {
            headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`}
        });

        const user = response.json()
        if (user?.email) {
            const { email, name } = user; // you will get more data in the user object
            .......
        }
    }
    catch(error){
        console.log('GoogleUserReq error: ', error);
    }
}

 return (
    <View>
      <Button 
        onPress={() => promptAsync() }
      />
    </View>
  );
```