# expo-auth-session cannot complete google login on android standalone app

Tags: android, react-native, authentication, expo, google-signin

I'm working on a react native app using expo. I've used `expo-auth-session/providers/google` package to sign-in. It is working fine in the expo environment but when I build the app for the android platform, nothing will happen as google sign-in doesn’t complete

[image]

Here is `AuthScreen` code:

```
...
import decode from 'jwt-decode';
import { ANDROID_CLIENT_ID, EXPO_CLIENT_ID, IOS_CLIENT_ID } from '../../env';
import * as Google from 'expo-auth-session/providers/google';
import * as WebBrowser from 'expo-web-browser';
...
import { useFocusEffect } from '@react-navigation/native';
...

WebBrowser.maybeCompleteAuthSession();

const AuthScreen = () => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [isSigningIn, setIsSigningIn] = useState(false);
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
  const [req, res, promtAsync] = Google.useIdTokenAuthRequest({
    expoClientId: EXPO_CLIENT_ID,
    androidClientId: ANDROID_CLIENT_ID,
    iosClientId: IOS_CLIENT_ID,
    scopes: ['profile', 'email'],
  });

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useFocusEffect(
    useCallback(() => {
      setIsLoading(true);
      loadFromStorage('user')
        .then(() => {
          setIsLoading(false);
          dispatch(setIsLoggedIn(true));
        })
        .catch(() => setIsLoading(false));
    }, []),
  );

  const onLogin = () =>
    promtAsync()
      .then((response) => {
        console.log({ res, req });
        if (response?.type === 'success') {
          const userInfo = decode(response?.params?.id_token);
          if (response?.params?.id_token) {
            setIsSigningIn(true);
            setIsLoading(true);
            login({
              google_id_token: response?.params?.id_token,
              name: userInfo?.name,
              profile_image: userInfo?.picture,
              agent: Platform.OS,
            })
              .then((res) => {
                const jwtToken = res?.headers?.['jwt-token'];
                saveToStorage({
                  key: 'jwtToken',
                  value: jwtToken,
                });
                saveToStorage({ key: 'user', value: userInfo });
                setIsSigningIn(false);
                setIsLoading(false);
                dispatch(setIsLoggedIn(true));
              })
              .catch(() => {
                console.log('Unable to sign-in.');
                setIsSigningIn(false);
                setIsLoading(false);
              });
          }
        }
      })
      .catch(() => {
        console.log('Unable to sign-in.');
        setIsSigningIn(false);

        setIsLoading(false);
      });

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {isLoading ? (
        <Loader />
      ) : (
        <>
          <ErpLogo />
          <TouchableNativeFeedback onPress={onLogin}>
            <GoogleSignInButton style={styles.googleButton} />
          </TouchableNativeFeedback>
        </>
      )}
      {isSigningIn && (
        <Text
          style={{
            position: 'absolute',
            bottom: Dimensions.get('screen').height / 30,
            fontFamily: fonts.firaSans400,
            color: colors.textColor,
          }}
        >
          Signing in...
        </Text>
      )}
    </View>
  );
};


export default AuthScreen;
```

and here is my `app.json` file:

```json
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "X",
    "slug": "x",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "owner": "xyz",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/img/erp.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "scheme": "com.xxx.xx",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": ["**/*"],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.xxx.xx",
      "buildNumber": "1.0.0"
    },
    "android": {
      "package": "com.xxx.xx",
      "versionCode": 1,
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
      },
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I get response type `dismiss`

Comment: Could you fix it?