# How to fix Google-auth in expo Error "Something went wrong when trying to finish signing in"

Tags: react-native, expo, google-oauth

```
When I click on my button Login , I'm redirected to this screen saying "Something went wrong when trying to finish signing in. Please close this screen to go back to the app".
```

//Google auth code:

```js
import * as Google from 'expo-auth-session/providers/google';

 const [request, response, promptAsync] = Google.useAuthRequest({
   expoClientId: config.google.expoClientId,
 androidClientId: config.google.androidClientId,
      });

React.useEffect(() => {
      //Handle google login
      console.log(response)
      if (response?.type === 'success') {
       const { authentication } = response;
      } 
      }, [response]);

// Button that calls the google sign in

<Button title="login" onPress={() => promptAsync({useProxy: false, showInRecents: true })} />
```

Comment: Duplicate of this I think: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70286836/how-to-fix-google-expo-auth-session-sign-in-error-something-went-wrong-when-try/74085310#74085310

Comment: have you any solution please?

Comment: This was the solution for me: you have to use host.expo.exponent as your package name and bundle identifier in the google developer console for this library to work.

Comment: host.exp.exponent  or host.expo.exponent??

Comment: Try both of them.